# Passing items in a list into a sql query in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
testlist=['abc', 'cde', 'def']
testvar='phone'

query = "select column1,column2, column3 from testtable where column4=%(var1)s and column5 in %(listitem)s "

content=pd.read_sql(query, con=mydb, params= {"var1":testvar, "listitem":testlist})
```

Error

`Failed processing pyformat-parameters; Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type`

How do we pass a list of items into a "IN" parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the list to a string. I guess by passing a `list()` to `listitem` the query cannot be created and throws this error.

```py
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
testlist=['abc', 'cde', 'def']
testvar='phone'

query = "select column1,column2, column3 from testtable where column4=%(var1)s and column5 in %(listitem)s "

content=pd.read_sql(query, con=mydb, params= {"var1":testvar, "listitem": str(testlist)})
```